# Windows7 Virtualbox guest in seamless mode has bottom clipped off in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: virtualbox, 13.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and Virtualbox 4.2.10-dfsg-0ubuntu2 with guest extensions installed and my Windows7 guests running in Seamless mode have the bottom part chopped off. The Windows Start button is slightly taller so it peaks out from below and that visible bit is clickable. This did not occur in 12.04.

It seems like the Virtualbox seamless boundaries end too high up (perhaps they start at the top behind the Ubuntu top panel) and the boundaries are not in sync with the Windows guest, or else the Windows Start menu/taskbar would also just appear higher up and not chopped off at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried enabling the 3D Acceleration Mode for the vm but that didn't help.

[image]

EDIT:

- I am running the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers (nvidia-310 310.44-0ubuntu2)
- I have disabled the global menu
- I am using sloppy mouse focus

I will try to put this back to stock Ubuntu 13.04 and see if that fixes the problem.

UPDATE:
 Restoring global menus did not fix the problem.

UPDATE (2013-05-02):
 I was resizing the window of a program running in the Windows7 guest and when my mouse cursor hit the bottom of the screen, it seems the entire guest desktop pans down. But this left things less usable so I had to restart the guest vm. I suspect this has something to do with the interaction between Unity's top panel and Virtualbox since the effected parts are the height of the top panel.

Comment: I'm having 100% same issue (host: 13.04, guest: XP 64bit, VirtualBox: 4.2.12). Difference: Intel HD Graphics, so at least we can exclude this being Nvidia-only issue. I didn't have this in 12.10. / Btw, you don't need to restart if things become "unsable" - use the Host key+L (Host key: right Ctrl?) to turn off seamless mode.

Comment: I took a quickish look at at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) and [VirtualBox's bugtracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/search?link&q=&ticket=on), found nothing relevant with the keywords I used. :(

Comment: Having the same problem with AMD Graphics so +1 to it not being a graphics driver issue. Worked until upgrade to 13.04 which makes me think its a unity/compiz regression. Edit: Logged in to Gnome-shell (mutter/gnome3) and it works. I'm assuming this is a bug with virtualbox caused by a change in unity/compiz.

Comment: @Josh Also tested with another DE (MATE), and it works. I think a bug should be filed but is there yet enough information?

Comment: Might not be related to this issue, but once (has happened only once, can't find a way to repro) every window opened in the virtual machine (in seamless mode) resulted in a new Unity Launcher icon (multiple icons for the Virtualbox).

Comment: Interesting: if I start the virtual machine, put it to seamless mode and THEN enable OR disable external display: suddenly it works correctly. I guess something display/Unity/Compiz related gets reloaded after applying new display settings. Another lead...

Comment: @pileofrocks, you found a workaround, thanks :) Also LXDE and KDE work correct.

Comment: I posted [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1202936), so if someone wants to raise it's priority, please make me a favor.

Comment: What happens if you hide the windows bar, then start it?

Answer (score -1):

I had essentially the opposite problem, windows host and a Ubuntu 13.03 guest.  However the resolution to my problem may be what you need as well- perhaps setting the resolution this way on your Ubuntu host will solve the problem with your windows guest:

[Screen Resolution issue on Ubuntu 13.04 installed under Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292408/screen-resolution-issue-on-ubuntu-13-04-installed-under-virtualbox/293608#293608)

Comment: Nope. Was that issue even about seamless mode? Everything works correctly in non-seamless mode and it ONLY affects Virtualbox, everything else in host-Ubuntu displays correctly.