# Screen Resolution issue on Ubuntu 13.04 installed under Virtualbox

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, resolution, remote-desktop

I have Host OS -Windows-7 and Guest OS -Ubuntu 13.04.
Problem is when I open any web-page in browser e.g firefox, I can't see the bottom of web-page. I'm facing same issue with Remote Desktop connection using Remmina RDC.

Comment: Please further elaborate what exactly it is that is not displayed. A screenshot may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and am running a 13.04 guest, I could not see the virtualbox menu tab and fullscreen windows would extend below the bottom of the monitor.
Here is how I resolved it:
As reference, take a look at these-
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8595940

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Even though the resolution was set correctly in the "display" tool, the only thing that fixed it was setting it manually.
First I tested to be sure with xrandr:

```
xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

I had to minimize back to my host desktop (win8) and then back to the vm before I could see the virtualbox menu tab again, but the resolution changed immediately and no longer extended below the monitor.
I wanted the change every time I logged in, so I did:

```
vim ~/.xprofile
```

And then entered into the new file:

```
# To correct resolution error 
xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

This has resolved the problem for me.